# How to SPLIT a record into 2 records in SSIS data flow task

Tags: ssis

I have a record in which there are three columns called Phone,HomePhone and WorkPhone,and corresponding to  that I have another three Columns called PhoneDNC,HomePhoneDNC and WorkPhoneDNC.

**SCENARIO**
Lets say the Phone column has a value and so as the corresponding PhoneDNC has "1" and HomePhone has a value and HomephoneDNC has "0" and WorkPhone has no value and WorkPhoneDNC is NULL.

I have two flat-files named CALL and DONTCALL.

How can I split the record in such a way that if the DNC column(any of the PhoneDNC,OtherPhoneDNC,WorkPhoneDNC) has 1 then only that NUMBER will go to the file CALL,making the remaining Phone(any of the Phone,OtherPhone,WorkPhone whose corresponding DNC is 0) NULL for the same record. (In the CALL FILE)

if the DNC(any of the PhoneDNC,OtherPhoneDNC,WorkPhoneDNC) column has 0 then the corresponding number will go to the file DONTCALL making the remaining Phone(any of the Phone,OtherPhone,WorkPhone whose corresponding DNC is 1) NULL for the same record. (In the DONTCALL FILE)

If any of the Number has NULL value then I dont have to put it in any file.

I am using VisualStudio 2005.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Conditional split](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886.aspx) transformation. It's fairly easy to set up and it should do the trick.

Let me know if you have any questions